# How to configure an IPP-driverless printer with static IP address in CUPS?

Tags: network-printer, cups, mdns, avahi

I've recently bought a new network printer and it supports [driverless printing over IPP](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting). It works out of the box on Ubuntu 20.04 using CUPS with cups-browsed configured like this:

```
CreateIPPPrinterQueues Driverless
```

Cool so far. A few seconds after the printer is started, two new printers/queues (duplicate, a separate issue?) are created by CUPS.

I can also discover the printer like this:

```
$ driverless
ipp://Canon%20MF645C%20(a4%3Ab3%3A6b)%20(a4%3Ab3%3A6b)%20(2)._ipp._tcp.local/
```

However, sometimes halfway a print job the printer appears to disconnect and I get "Printer disappeared or cups-browsed shutdown" in the system tray for the printer queue.

[image: "Printer disappeared or cups-browsed shutdown"]

After that I can restart my PC or do whatever I want, but the printer won't be discovered again (`driverless` yields no output). It appears that somehow the discovery over the network stops for quite a while. Not sure what is the problem, but I can connect to the printer just fine over IPP on its IP address (avoiding multicast DNS issues).

So, I'd like to just avoid using multicast DNS and configure it by its static IP address instead. How do I add a printer with a *driverless* configuration in CUPS, but without having to rely on the buggy mDNS implementation? When adding a printer in CUPS administration Web GUI using the manual URI `ipp://10.1.2.3/`, I cannot select "driverless" or something, I have to provide a PPD I do not have and the model isn't listed (it's a fairly new model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a command-line way to add the printer:

```
lpadmin -p myprintername -E -v ipp://10.1.2.3/ipp/print -m everywhere
```

---

Do NOT make the mistake to omit `/ipp/print` at the end there. I had omitted it and then any print job I send will just infinitely loop in the number of pages and never prints...

[image]

(this number of pages keeps growing every second and my CPU is at 100%...)